# Liquibase - Create index not creating

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to use the following Liquibase change sets to create indexes for my Postgres database table:

```
<changeSet author="xxxx" id="1120-000-1-index1">
    <createIndex indexName="yyyyyyyyyyyy" tableName="tableX">
        <column name="some_date"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="xxxx" id="1120-000-1-index2">
    <createIndex indexName="xxxxxxxxxx" tableName="tableX">
        <column name="updated_at"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

When I run it, there is no error but the log states: *INFO  [main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - Index created for collection null"* and the indexes are not created.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: When I checked the documentation for createIndex, the SQL example looks very different than what you have here - could it be the format of your SQL changelog is the culprit here? Link to relevant section of docs: https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-index.html#:~:text=JSON%20example-,SQL%20example,-%2D%2D%20changeset%20DocUser%3A1

Comment: I don't think I understood your comment. This XML is very similar to the one in the doc you linked. The changelog is automatically created by Liquibase so I don't know how its format could be the problem

Comment: I apologize, @Tomas, I completely misunderstood what you were asking. I've brought your question to our Liquibase Community Support team and I'll get back to you soon with an update.

Comment: Well, it appears you have found a bug! Please follow this procedure to report and the team will investigate. https://www.liquibase.org/community/contribute/report-bugs